# htaccess to remove query string from a single url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, query-string

I've researched this lots and seen many similar posts but no solution seems to work for this exact situation. I want to remove the query string from a single URL in my site (but keep all other query strings unchanged elsewhere). Im using wordpress which generates a URL:

http://mysite.net/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.net

Unfortunately i cant change the generated url so i wanted to use HTACCESS to 301 this to just:

http://mysite.net/wp-login.php

My current HTACCESS is below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

I have tried many suggested solutions so far without success which i suspect is because of clashes with my current htaccess modifications leading to 500 Server Errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this right below `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.net$
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ /wp-login.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you Jon Lin!

Comment: @user1527123 accept the answer also .. so that others know this is the correct answer and jon will get points for it :)